# Calculating accurate volume of loaded trucks using LIDAR sensor data

Tags: python, sensors, volume, point-clouds, lidar

I am currently working with LIDAR sensors LMS511 and LMS111. With these sensors, I obtain XYZ points and data from which I can plot a 3D point cloud using the XYZ coordinates. Using this data, I can find the trucks' length, width, and height by analyzing the variation points in the measurement data points that i get from the sensors.

However, I am facing an issue with accurate volume calculation when the truck is loaded with mining items. The calculations are correct when the truck is empty, but variations in the loaded truck's cargo present challenges. The load might only fill half or a quarter of the truck, or the mining items might be heaped irregularly.

I'm looking for advice on the techniques or formulas that can be used to calculate the accurate volume of the loaded truck in these scenarios. If anyone has experience or knowledge in this area, I would greatly appreciate your valuable insights and solutions. This information is crucial for completing my project successfully.

Thank you in advance for your help.